# Mule ESB - Clear Memory of a batch process

Tags: memory, mule

My Scenario is I have 4 batches in a my Mule flow. One of the batch say batch 1 loads records of say 10,000 but then i decided to force stop the batch. Now i decided to run batch No. 2 in the same XML. The batch 2 runs but the batch 1 records which were earlier loaded also gets run. Is this a bug or is there are a configuration to prevent this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running the batch on Studio?

If yes, go to the Run Configurations on studio. Look for the configuration of your project and scroll down to 'Clear Application Data', set this to 'Always'.

[image: Configuration]