# Mule 4 Runtime - Clear Application Data of a batch process

Tags: mule, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb, mule4

I was having intermittent issue running a Mule Batch with huge data in Anypoint Studio. That issue is resolved by enabling 'Always' option under 'Clear Application Data' in 'Run Configurations' (as per the given instruction in [Mule ESB - Clear Memory of a batch process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948831/mule-esb-clear-memory-of-a-batch-process)). That option is shown in the picture.

How to enable the same 'Always' option in stand alone Mule Runtime during the startup that means when we are not running the batch from Anypoint Studio? Is there any command line argument available that can be used in startup script of the Mule Runtime to achieve the same goal?

[image]

Comment: What is the actual issue you are having in the standalone environment?

Comment: Same issue what we were having in Anypoint Studio before selecting that "Always" Clear Application Data option. The issue is that not always for all records batch was getting triggered and it was intermittent issue.

Answer (score 0):

By deleting the local data you are deleting batch queues, persistent objects stores and maybe some other information. In a development environment like Anypoint Studio IDE it is usually OK but for a standalone Mule Runtime it means you are deleting production data, for example records that are used by batch to continue processing after a restart. That data will be *lost*. Having said that, it might be needed if the data is completely corrupted.

It is a best practice and a strong advice to any user to resolve the root cause of the issue rather than delete data. And it should never be done every time you start your production Mule, only when there is absolutely no other alternative.

**I don't recommend to delete local files at all**. If even after my warnings you absolutely need to do this **never ever delete the .mule directory**. If you still want to risk losing data delete only the directory with the application name under the .mule directory.